# Table in azure databricks does not update or overwrite its contents. How could I programmatically do it using python code?

Tags: python, azure, databricks

In Azure Databricks the table is already created and I'd like to overwrite it's contents by running a job everyday/

I've tried using `dataframe.write.saveAsTable("table_name")` and the table was created. It shows an error after running again showing: "The table has already created"

Also tried:

`dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("table_name")` but only the dataframe gets updated and not the table.

```
dataframe.write.format("table_name") \
     .mode('overwrite').option("header", "true")

Out[23]: <pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameWriter at 0x7fe13c2f79e8>
```

but the table still does not get overwritten by the recent data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to overwrite new dataframe data to the table with the same name.

Please try to use the code below.

1. To use [`mode(saveMode)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.mode) with `overwrite` value before `saveAsTable`.

   [image]

   `dataframe.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('table_name')`
2. To use [`saveAsTable(name, format=None, mode=None, partitionBy=None, **options)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable) with the parameter `mode`.

   [image]

   `dataframe.write.saveAsTable('table_name', mode="overwrite")`

   Or

   `dataframe.write.saveAsTable('table_name', None, "overwrite", None)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. I used this: dataframe_name.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database_name.table_name")